# What is the crashlytics alternative in AWS services?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I use crashlytics to get crash reports from my android app but since i already use aws services i wanted to migrate crash reports to AWS.
I googled and found about AWS Mobile analytics but seems like its more than just crash reporting. so can anyone please suggest me an alternative from AWS, which is specifically for crashes?

Comment: Take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/extend-with-cloud-functions

Comment: I want to migrate from firebase to aws @RameesThattarath

Comment: I havent seen a crash reporting tool for AWS, but there is analytics service in which you will have catch the uncaught exceptions yourself and report via analytics sdk, I dont think you can migrate from firebase crashlytics, you will have to opt out of firebase crashlytics and implement it yourself via AWS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, there is no mobile crash reporting and analytic tool provided by AWS.

Comment: Same need here. I see that the last reply is 4 years old. Any updates since then?

Answer (score -6):

i would recommend
https://www.fabric.io . 
its easy to use and for free

Comment: it is actually the crashlytics

Comment: Fabric was discontinued in leu of crashlytics.